# StringSplit is chopping off a character

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a hotkey setup like this:

```
Numpad1::
ClipSave := ClipboardAll
Send, ^+{Left}^+{Left}
Send ^x
StringSplit, Commands, Clipboard, {Space}
Send, local{Space}
Send, %Commands1%
Send, {Space}={Space}
Send, %Commands2%
Return
```

Given the input `lua 1`, it should produce `local lua = 1`. But, it produces `Local lu = 1`. Why and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use %A_Space% rather than {Space}

```
Numpad1::
ClipSave := ClipboardAll
Send, ^+{Left}^+{Left}
Send ^x
StringSplit, Commands, Clipboard, %A_Space%
Send, local{Space}
Send, %Commands1%
Send, {Space}={Space}
Send, %Commands2%
Return
```

produces local lua = 1 from lua 1 over here, wheras {Space} gives lu, as you experienced :)